# MySql function not returning the correct result

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm trying to create a function in mysql which will return boolean if the id already exist in the table. Most of the solutions that I found online require solutions using both php and mysql but what I'm trying to do is a solution purely in mysql in the form of a function.

My simplifed mysql table will be as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    `user_id` VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE,
    `name` VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);
```

My first attempt was below:

```
DELIMITER *
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CheckExistId*
CREATE FUNCTION CheckExistId (user_id VARCHAR(12)) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
    DECLARE isExist BOOL;
    SET isExist = 0;
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `user_id`=user_id) INTO isExist ;
    RETURN isExist;
END*
DELIMITER ;
```

My second attempt:

```
DELIMITER *
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CheckExistId*
CREATE FUNCTION CheckExistId (user_id VARCHAR(12)) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
    DECLARE isExist BOOL;
    DECLARE countRow INT;
    SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) INTO countRow FROM table1 WHERE `user_id`=user_id;
    IF countRow = 0 THEN SET isExist = 1; 
    ELSE SET isExist = 0; 
    END IF;
    RETURN isExist;
END*
DELIMITER ;
```

Both didn't give me the result that I expected. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Could it be a problem that in #1 you use an asterisk as a delimiter, but then have an asterisk (star)  in your select statement? Not sure - just guessing.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: @kimsia nope. building a simple php/mysql system for office.

Comment: @FreudianSlip yeah maybe.. will check now.

Comment: @ImpStudent In that case, can you help me understand why there is a need to do this purely in mysql?

Comment: @kimsia just part of the learning process. surely it should be possible to create a function to achieve this right? i just dont understand why both my attempt don't work. just curious to find out what i did wrong there.

Comment: @FreudianSlip changed the delimiter but still didn't produce the intended outcome

Comment: @ImpStudent Possible yes. But to achieve the objective of simply getting your app to work, then I thought it is more important to get the app to work regardless the solution is to use pure mysql or not. I see that you have accepted an answer, so I guess now the point is moot. I used pure mysql to have complex logic before. It was not maintainable for me in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt was quite fine, except that you're using `*` as delimiter and using the same name for your parameter and column name. That's confusing MySQL. Write it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CheckExistId $$
CREATE FUNCTION CheckExistId (p_user_id VARCHAR(12)) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
    DECLARE isExist BOOL;
    SET isExist = 0;
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `user_id`=p_user_id) INTO isExist ;
    RETURN isExist;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this works for me! i didn't know that we cant use same name for parameter and column name.. thanks!

Comment: Same story with parameter and column name. And shouldn't it be `IF countRow = 0 THEN SET isExist = 0; ELSE SET isExist = 1;`? or shorter `IF countRow = 0 THEN RETURN 0; ELSE RETURN 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TableTT2`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableTT2 (
    `user_id` VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE,
    `name` VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `TableTT2` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a1'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a2'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a3'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a4'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a5'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a6'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a7'), 
(LEFT(UUID(), 12), 'a8');


    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE FUNCTION `CheckExistId`(usrId varchar(12)) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN

    DECLARE totalCnt INT;
    DECLARE resBool BOOL;
    SET totalCnt = 0 ;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO totalCnt FROM TableTT2 WHERE user_id = usrID; 
    SET resBool = IF(totalCnt <> 0, TRUE, FALSE);
    RETURN resBool;

END


SELECT * FROM TableTT2;
SELECT CheckExistId('fe3faa00-0b0');
SELECT CheckExistId('fe3faa00-111');
```

Hope this helps. It might be an issue using * delimiter and a second issue that i noticed your function parameter is a varchar even if you check by an integer id.

Comment: i was trying to understand ur code.. why is there two RETURN statement? by the way i corrected already that the id is supposed to be in varchar(12) and not int as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: my bad a typo for return statement and should work for vrachar i updated the code

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER *
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS CheckExistId*
CREATE FUNCTION CheckExistId (user_id VARCHAR(12)) RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
             SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `user_id`=user_id)
        THEN RETURN 1 

        ELSE RETURN 0 
    END
END*
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: seems like its not working for me. firstly the error with the delimiter. i changed it to // and test again. it now throws a syntax error, unexpected return_sym at "then return 1".